# Qt image I/O and QPixmap::grabWindow

Tags: c++, image, qt, io

I'm writing a kind of "Remote Desktop" program and I got stuck with a few points.
I use QPixmap::grabWindow on the server side to capture the screenshot and send it to client, which in turn is written to QByteArray and is sent via QTcpSocket.
The size of the resulting QPixmap is too big and as you understand the application is time critical. Is there a way to optimize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In addition to Michael's more detailed answer:) For compression you can use qCompress / qUncompress (which actually depends on Qt's included zlib) http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#qUncompress

Answer (score 1):

- Use deltas.  The basic idea is this: imagine a grid overlaying the window image, that divides it into 16px by 16px or so squares.  Compare each square with the corresponding one in the previous window that was sent to the client.  If so much as one pixel has changed, send the square's new content to the client.
- Try compressing the image using some form of quick compression.  You could use [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) for example, but keep the compression level at 3 or below.  Or you could compress the entire data stream as it is being sent via TCP (this is tricky - you have to be careful to flush buffers and such.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Michaels answer:

- Reduce resolution
- Reduce color depth
- Reduce frame rate
- Use a screencast codec / decoder